# How to have a struct field with the same mutability as the parent struct?

Tags: rust, mutable

I'm trying to wrap a slice in a struct so that I will be able to instantiate the struct mutably or immutably. Here's a minimal example:

```
use std::ops::{ Index, IndexMut };

struct Test<'a, T: 'a> {
    inner: &'a[T]
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Test<'a, T> {
    fn new (inner: &'a[T]) -> Self { Test { inner: inner } }
}

impl<'a, T> Index<usize> for Test<'a, T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index (&self, i: usize) -> &T { &self.inner[i] }
}

impl<'a, T> IndexMut<usize> for Test<'a, T> {
   fn index_mut (&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut T { &mut self.inner[i] }
}

fn main() {
    let store = [0; 3];
    let test = Test::new (&store);
    println!("{}", test[1]);

    let mut mut_store = [0; 3];
    let mut mut_test = Test::new (&mut mut_store);
    mut_test[1] = 42;
    println!("{}", mut_test[1]);
}
```

This doesn't compile: "cannot borrow immutable indexed content `self.inner[..]` as mutable".

I could get it to compile by changing the definition of `inner` to be of type `&'a mut[T]`, but then `inner` is mutable even when I don't need it to be (in the above example, I must then declare `store` as mutable too even though `test` is immutable).

Is there a way to make it so that the mutability of `inner` follows the mutability of the `Test` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well said in the question, this code compiles:

```
struct Test<'a, A: 'a> {
  inner: &'a mut A,
}

fn main() {
    let t = Test { inner: &mut 5i32 };

    *t.inner = 9;
}
```

It is indeed possible to mutate a borrowed element, even when the borrowing content is immutable. This is a case where you must choose your guarantees, while keeping in mind that the mutability of a binding is always independent of the borrowed content's mutability.

Right now, I can think of two possible solutions: you can encapsulate the borrowed content over methods that depend on `self`'s mutability ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0d380e53a068560fe606d219ec22ed94&version=stable&backtrace=0), will no longer compile):

```
impl<'a, A: 'a> Test<'a, A> {
    fn inner(&self) -> &A {
        self.inner
    }

    fn inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut A {
        self.inner
    }
}
```

Although you still need to keep a borrow to mutable content, it can no longer be mutated from an immutable binding of `Test`. If you also need it to point to immutable content, you should consider having two different structs ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=22bca09430bc402d047f4373669ec8a5&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
struct Test<'a, A: 'a> {
    inner: &'a A,
}

impl<'a, A: 'a> Test<'a, A> {
    fn inner(&self) -> &A {
        self.inner
    }
}

struct TestMut<'a, A: 'a> {
    inner: &'a mut A,
}

impl<'a, A: 'a> TestMut<'a, A> {
    fn inner(&self) -> &A {
        self.inner
    }

    fn inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut A {
        self.inner
    }
}
```

There is a third option: to keep both kinds of borrows exclusively with an enum. At this point however, using the borrowed content as mutable requires run-time checks.